# How to check element height after calling jQuery animate

Tags: jquery

I've coded the following, but have found that the height check statement does not work as expected.

I'm trying to make something happen if the height of an element `#tube` is below 10.

The elements height `#tube` is affected when it is clicked. `console.log` shows me the elements current height, so i know the height's value can be obtained.

But for some reason it's just not working - it may be due to poor jQuery grammar (not sure what the term should be)  would really appreciate any help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $circle = $(".circle"),
    $tube = $("#tube"),
    $boob = $("#boob"),
    $bigCircle = $("#bigCircle"),
    tubeMinHeight = 10;

  $boob.hide();
  $circle.draggable();
  $bigCircle.click(function() {
    $(this).effect("shake", "slow");
    $("body").jGravity({
       target: ".circle",
       ignoreClass: "#bigCircle",
       weight: 25,
       depth: 1,
       drag: true
    });
  });

  $tube.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.hide(200);
      $tube.animate({
        height: "+=10"
      }, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');
      $tube.click(function() {
        $tube.animate({
          height: "-=10"
        }, 'fast', 'easeOutBounce');

        /* if statement below in question! */
        if ( $tube.height() === 0 ) {
           $boob.show(100);
           console.log("working");
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $("#button").click(function(){
     console.log( $tube.height() );
  }); 
});
```

I'm quite new to jQuery/Javascript and so I'm giving myself little exercises to learn. Layman's terms would be appreciated!

Here's a link to the exercise - http://codepen.io/ianranasinghe/pen/XdpZNN?

Comment: wtf kind of animation is this? "boob", "bigCircle", "shake", "easeOutBounce"... Weird dude, weird.

Comment: FYI, the downvotes most likely came from the sub-optimal title your question had. "Not working" is widely frowned upon as an error description (and as a question title anyway), so next time just put some more work into your title - the rest of the question was pretty fine by SO standards.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! @Tomalak

Comment: And @8protons I was just choosing the first words that came into my head haha! It sounds weird when you put it like that, but It's not rude in any way I promise!

Comment: @IanRanasinghe Haha I was just wondering! Thanks for not taking offense because I didn't mean any :] Happy coding!

Comment: Don't forget to pick an answer as accepted to close down the thread. (@trincot's answer is the most complete one)

Comment: Would not have known to do that, thanks @Tomalak!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is related to animations running asynchronously:

Look at this part of the code:

```
 $(tube).animate({
     height: "-=10"
 }, 'fast', 'easeOutBounce');

 if ( $(tube).height() === 0 ) {
     $(boob).show(100);
     console.log("working");
 };
```

The [`animate` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) will start when you call it, but will not immediately reduce the height with 10. The method will just schedule with `setTimeout` the gradual decrease of the height, but will return immediately. So the actual height decrease will happen later, i.e. after the rest of the currently running code ends.

This means that your test for 0 will always return false.

Then when soon after the height really has become 0, you cannot click that element any more, and so this code will never run when the height is actually 0.

Luckily, jQuery can inform you when the animation has completed; you can pass a callback, as follows:

```
 $(tube).animate({
     height: "-=10"
 }, 'fast', 'easeOutBounce', function () {
     // if we get here, the animation has finished
     if ( $(tube).height() === 0 ) {
         $(boob).show(100);
         console.log("working");
     };
 });
```

Please note that currently you are assigning the click event handler on the tube element every time something is dropped on it. This cannot be the intention. Just define it once, outside of the drop handler.

Comment: It works!!!!! thank you so much, your explanation made perfect sense and I've learned something as a result, much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are ending your if statement's closing bracket with a semicolon. If statements do not need to be closed with a semicolon.

```
if ( $(tube).height() === 0 ) {
  $(boob).show(100);
  console.log("working");
}//notice no semicolon
```

Without any more code, such as the HTML document, this is all I see wrong.

Comment: They don't need to but they will work just fine if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!! Still doesn't seem to be working - here's a link to the exercise! http://codepen.io/ianranasinghe/pen/XdpZNN?

Answer (score 0):

`.animate()` takes a while to complete, but the code does not wait for it. The `if` in the following runs immediately after the animation has started, not after the animation has finished, as you expect:

```
$tube.animate({
    height: "-=10"
}, 'fast', 'easeOutBounce');

if ( $tube.height() < tubeMinHeight ) {
   $boob.show(100);
}
```

To make it run after the animation has finished, jQuery allows you to place a callback function in the queue, like this:

```
$tube.animate({
    height: "-=15"
}, 'fast', 'easeOutBounce', function () {
  if ( $tube.height() < tubeMinHeight ) {
     $boob.show(100);
  }
});
```

See this live example (expand and run):

```js
$(function () {
  $("#foo").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "-=20"
    }, 'fast', 'swing', function () {
      if ( $(this).height() < 100 ) {
         $("#bar").show(100);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
#bar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click the rectangle a few times:
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar">Now it's less than 100px!</div>
```

See the [documentation on `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Thanks Tomalak and thanks for editing my first post, learned a different way to declare variables as a result!

Comment: The use of `$xyz` is a common convention for denoting variables that contain jQuery objects. It's not technically necessary but it makes reading jQuery code easier, so it's a good habit to pick up.